# My Hitachi HDD cannot be read or written to, but SMART results and others are OK. Why?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I do not care about any data on the drive and I do not intend to store important data on the drive in future - this is purely an academic exercise!

---

Attempting to read or write results in a failure:

```shell
$sudo dd if=/dev/sda count=1
dd: error reading '/dev/sda': Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.150944 s, 0.0 kB/s

$sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=1
dd: writing to '/dev/sda': Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.143382 s, 0.0 kB/s

$sudo parted -l
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore?
```

`dmesg` reports the following information:

```shell
[84718.986340] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA
[84718.986349] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 29 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[84718.986353] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[84718.986356] ata2.00: error: { ABRT }
[84718.988611] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[84718.988622] ata2: EH complete
[84719.006316] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[84719.006322] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[84719.006327] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA
[84719.006336] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 14 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[84719.006340] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[84719.006343] ata2.00: error: { ABRT }
[84719.008482] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[84719.008496] ata2: EH complete
[84719.034310] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[84719.034315] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[84719.034319] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA
[84719.034327] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 28 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[84719.034331] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[84719.034333] ata2.00: error: { ABRT }
[84719.036471] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[84719.036481] ata2: EH complete
[84719.054321] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[84719.054326] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[84719.054329] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA
[84719.054337] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 13 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[84719.054341] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[84719.054343] ata2.00: error: { ABRT }
[84719.056483] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[84719.056493] ata2: EH complete
[84719.078307] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[84719.078311] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[84719.078314] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA
[84719.078322] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 30 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[84719.078326] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[84719.078328] ata2.00: error: { ABRT }
[84719.080521] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[84719.080536] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[84719.080540] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[84719.080543] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[84719.080547] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[84719.080550] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[84719.080555] buffer_io_error: 15 callbacks suppressed
[84719.080557] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[84719.080578] ata2: EH complete
```

It shows up with `lsblk`:

```shell
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
```

SMART results are perfect for a drive of this age, and it will happily complete a full self-test without errors:

```shell
$sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda                                                                
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.11-1-default] (SUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Travelstar 5K500.B
Device Model:     Hitachi HTS545050B9A300
Serial Number:    100329PBN40017GNHJNE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 5f0c951bf
Firmware Version: PB4OC64G
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Fri Jan 11 19:39:05 2019 NZDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  645) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 158) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   110   110   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       4327
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   175   175   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       7314
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   120   120   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       32
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       6497
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       3485
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65660
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       105680
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   183   183   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 2/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6481         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6453         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6447         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6445         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

`hdparm` reports that no ATA security features are enabled, and I've also been able to run an `ata-secure-erase` command successfully, with no change.

```shell
$sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       Hitachi HTS545050B9A300                 
        Serial Number:      100329PBN40017GNHJNE
        Firmware Revision:  PB4OC64G
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 7208 KBytes (type=DualPortCache)
        Form Factor: 2.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Advanced power management level: 128
        Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 254
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
           *    Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
                Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
                Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
                In-order data delivery
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
                enabled
                locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        Security level high
        156min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 158min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000cca5f0c951bf
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000cca
        Unique ID       : 5f0c951bf
Checksum: correct
```

Results are reproducible on multiple computers, including via USB and internally. No obvious damage to the drive.

I'm pretty sure it's not an internal mechanical issue, as full SMART tests complete successfully.

I don't think it's a connector or transmission error, as the `UDMA_CRC_Error_Count` is zero, and I can read SMART/ATA data fine.

It has had a full secure erase (multiple times), so I doubt that any data stored on the drive (partition tables etc) are confusing the OS. Especially given the use of low-level tools.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Definitely odd. Any error messages in `dmesg` after you try to read/write with `dd`?

Comment: @dirkt dmesg output added. That note about `unaligned write command` makes me think maybe I've confused the drive into being 4K but advertising 512B or something?

Comment: Alignment is definitely working looking into. Play with `bs=512`, `bs=4096`, and various `oseek=` and `count=` to see if you can get it to work. You can see/set what the kernel assumes about physical/logical sector size and offset somewhere in `/proc` or `/sys`, and you may have to change that, but I'd have to google it myself.

Comment: I... might be an idiot. It says security is enabled (no 'not'); I read it as being not enabled; it's the opposite of the asterisks for 'enabled' further up. Now I just have to remember the last password used and how to unlock it...

Comment: Yup. Drive was locked from the last time I tried to security erase it. I think it might have shut off mid way (power saving...), and rather than continue with the erase next time it was woken up, it just stayed locked.